# Datadog RUM mark elements to be excluded in the replay

Tags: css, datadog, pii, session-replay

I have a page that displays at one moment "Hello User!"
I would like to redact "User"(as it is Personal Identifiable Information) from the Datadog session replay but I could not find a way to do it. Is it possible to set some custom CSS class on the elements so that they will not be recorded?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this right now. You could put the data in non-support element per https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/session_replay/#some-html-elements-are-not-visible-at-replay e.g. on a canvas, but that's pretty hacky.

Comment: I will probably wrap the PII sensitive elements into a web component that has a <slot>.  That, according to DataDog would do the trick.